# open and close box(div) with css or jquery

Tags: jquery, css, show-hide

I am Iranian and Persian language
Translated into English by Google

First - I thank you for this good site

I have two boxes / Like the picture below

http://www.7upload.ir/uploads/u27405_box.jpg

I click on the arrows in each box
Box is opened or closed
And in all styles, fonts and colors .... To change

css is much better
But if it was okay jQuery

Thanks to all friends  Help me with whatever language they
Translate by google

Comment: I found the answer

Demo

'http://jsfiddle.net/gpHum/12/'


But When put the two box not working

'http://jsfiddle.net/gpHum/13/'

why ??? 

Please help me

Answer (score 1):

Here is a PURE CSS solution to your issue http://jsfiddle.net/gpHum/24/

however I won't call it proper solution as I am using `label` element to toggle `div`, instead `a` element should be preferred. But don't have luck with that right now!